# Pronunciation of the second /k/ in "excuse"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

The "p" in "application" is unaspirated and the "p" in "apply" is aspirated since it is the first letter in the stressed syllable, am I right? When an unvoiced stop is the first letter of a stressed syllable, it should always be aspirated, correct? But for example in the word "excuse" since the second "k" is the second letter but not the first letter of the stressed syllable, I should pronounce it as an unaspirated sound, shouldn't I? I mean in the word "excuse" the first "k" should be aspirated and the second "k" should be unaspirated, right?

Answer (score 2):

In English, ⟨p, t, k⟩ are [aspirated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7szkN4QcxI) when they're at the start of a syllable (usually stressed), so the ⟨p⟩ in *pie, pool, paper* is aspirated. However, when the ⟨p⟩ is at the end of a syllable or preceded by an /s/, it's unaspirated so in words like *map, spy, spin* etc., it's unaspirated.

As the OP pointed out, the ⟨p⟩ in *apply* is aspirated because it's at the start of a stressed syllable: [əˈpʰlaɪ] (or [əˈpl̥aɪ]<sup>1</sup>). By contrast, the ⟨p⟩ in *application* is unaspirated because it's at the end of the syllable: [ˌ**æp**.ləˈkeɪ.ʃn̩].

Now *excuse*: it can either be syllabified as /ɪk.**skjuːz**/ or /ɪks.**kjuːz**/, the first ⟨k⟩ in both the pronunciations is unaspirated. If you think of it as being derived from the prefix *ex-*, then it can be analysed as /**ɪks**.kjuːz/<sup>2</sup>, in which case the second [k] is aspirated: [ɪks.kʰjuːz]. However, if you don't have a morpheme boundary, then the second [k] is likely to be unaspirated because ⟨p, t, k⟩ are unaspirated when preceded by an [s]: [ɪk.skjuːz]. Some speakers do have a morpheme boundary in the word *excuse* so they aspirate the ⟨k⟩ while others think of it as single morpheme and don't aspirate the ⟨k⟩.

In a nutshell, aspiration of the voiceless stops in words like *sister, whisper, whiskey, excuse* etc., is controversial.

---

NOTES

1. When an (stressed) aspirated stop is followed by a liquid (/r, l/), the aspiration usually results in the voicelessness of the following liquid so for example *click* can be transcribed as [kʰlɪk] -> [kl̥ɪk]
2. We usually [syllabify bimorphemic/polymorphemic words](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/syllabif.htm) [at morpheme boundaries abc](http://seas3.elte.hu/phono-analysis/analysis8.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

*Ex*-, especially at the beginning of words, is special.

*Excuse* is pronounced like it's spelled "ek-scuse", as though the first half the *x* (the `/k/`) belongs to the first syllable and the other half (the `/s/` half) belongs to the second.

The first `/k/` won't be aspirated, the *c* will be.

Comment: If the /s/ really is at the beginning of the second syllable, then the 'c' (second /k/) will*not* be aspirated!!

Comment: Pronounce it and hold your hand to your mouth, you sure you aren't feeling a small puff of air from aspiration?  It's hardly as strongly aspirated as at the beginning of a word (like *cut*) but most English consonants are aspirated at least a little bit much of the time.  They don't sound like say Spanish or Russian with hardly any aspiration.

Comment: There's a little experiment you can do to see if there's any aspiration, but it won't work for /k/ 'cuz it's too far back in the mouth. You can try it with /p/ though. Rip a long narrow strip of paper off a page, hold the top and hang the lower edge in front of your lips. Now say *pie* loudly. The paper will get pushed sharply by the aspiration. Now say *spy* loudly. You'll find that the paper hardly moves because there isn't any aspiration. Now try *press* and *express*. You'll see the same effect. An /s/ at the beginning of a syllable prevents any aspiration on a following /p, t/ or /k/.

Comment: @Araucaria So you are saying that the first /k/ is aspirated and the second one is not? Btw as far as I know, the "p" in "spy" should be aspirated since there is a vowel after it.

Comment: @DereMemo No, the first /k/ isn't aspirated because it is at the end of a syllable (plosives in ends of syllables aren't aspirated). The /p/ in *spy* isn't aspirated, because it is preceded by an /s/.

Comment: @Araucaria Are you a native speaker?

Comment: @DereMemo I am!

Comment: @DereMemo [And I'm a tutor in English Phonetics at the UCL summer course in English Phonetics!](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/pals/study/cpd/cpd-courses/scep)

Comment: It seems like there is no consensus on this subject. For example you are saying that if a voiceless stop is at the end of a syllable, it should pronounced as an unaspirated sound, but many English teachers, linguists etc. don't agree with that all of them are always unaspirated at the ends of syllables. For example the  /k/ in "I like Superman" should be aspirated according to many people. Another example: You are saying that the /p/ in "express" should be unaspirated, but some linguists say that voiceless stops should be aspirated if /r/, /l/ and /w/ follow them.

Comment: @Araucaria But unless there is /s/ before a voiceless stop and if there is a vowel after it, it should be aspirated, right? I mean we can make an unaspirated sound only if there is an /s/ before them when there is a vowel which is following them? I can't think of an example word now but I think you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @DereMemo Not necessarily. There is a lot of aspiration in a stressed syllable, a little bit in a syllable following a stressed syllable and not much at all - if any - in a syllable before a stressed syllable. So in *potato* there will be a lot after the second /p/, a bit after the third, and none after the first.

Comment: @DereMemo I'm no expert in phonetics, but considering that "excuse" is pronounced differently, depending on whether it's being used as a noun or a verb, it seems like you need an answer that describes this difference.

Comment: @ Araucaria When I say "Your cheeks are big", should I make an unaspirated sound in the "k" of "cheeks"? I am so used to making an aspirated sound in that kind of words.

Comment: @DereMemo Yep, there's no aspiration in a /k/ at the end of a syllable.

Comment: @Araucaria But isn't /s/ the last letter in that syllable?

Comment: @DereMemo The syllable has three parts, an onset, a nucleus (usually a vowel), and a coda. So in *splints*, the onset is /spl/, the nucleus is /ɪ/ and the coda is /nts/. English plosives are never aspirated in codas.

Comment: @Araucaria Hi. I should aspirate the stop sound if a syllable ends with an /s/ sound and the next syllable starts with a stop sound, right? For example I should aspirate the stop sounds after the /s/ in the words like "destiny", "pastor", "biscuit", "frustrate" etc while I shouldn't aspirate them in the word like "excuse", "explain", "instrument" etc, right?